# Looking for open-source http servers

Tags: c, apache

I'm looking for open-source http servers as benchmarks for my OS, which should satisfy:

1. It folks several processes to handle http requests (not threads or I/O multiplexing)
2. It can be compiled statically, which means no run-time code link like dynamic libraries.

Is there any satisfied httpd? Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tryed [LightHttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/), small fast and simple ;-)

Comment: It seems lighttpd will load code at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache](http://www.apache.org/) should be fine -- it can be configured in either multi-process or multi-thread ways, after all, and of course it can be built with all static links!

Apache's crucial because it's the most popular one, but maybe you should also look at [nginx](http://nginx.net/) which is also deservedly popular (though still a niche player compared to Apache) and focused on one-master, many-workers processes architecture.

Comment: That's a little too complex since we'll debug our OS to run the server. Thanks anyway :-)